# pop from empty list error in car app

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm mostly new to this so apologies in advance if the answer is blindingly obvious to this. For a school assignment (and out of interest also) I'm building a sort of basic car app that uses lists to store cars (objects) as they are made then a separate list to record cars that are rented.

The rent process works perfectly fine and when I tested it it was appending a car to my rentedcars list, however when I call it (rentedcars) later in a separate function its saying that it cannot pop an empty list.

I assumed this was because the list was being modified inside a function, however when I returned the outputed modified list and assigned a variable to the function for later use it gave me the error that I was calling a variable before assigning it and giving the variable a global definition didn't resolve it.

The segment of code is below, anyone have any thoughts? It would be much appreciated. I've looked this sort of problem a couple of times on the forums here but the solutions (at least as I tried to implement them) didn't seem to fix it.

The function rental_system is called later, I've just shown the section I'm having problems with due to size, all lists for the 4 types of car are made under **init** self. etc and work.

```
def rent(self, car_list, rented_cars, amount):     # Process to rent a car function        
    if len(car_list) < amount:
        print 'Not enough cars in stock'     # Make sure enough cars in stock
        return
    total = 0
    while total < amount:
        carout = car_list.pop()          # Pop last item from given car list and return it
        rented_cars.append(carout)       # Then append to a new list of rented cars that are now unavailable
        total = total + 1
        print 'Make: ' + carout.getMake()       
        print 'Colour: ' + carout.getColour()
        print 'Engine Size(Cylinders): ' + carout.getEngineSize()            
    print 'You have rented ' + str(amount) + ' car(s)'       
    return rented_cars

def rented(self, car_list, rented_cars, amount):  # Process for returning cars        
    total = 0
    while total < amount:
        carin = rented_cars.pop()
        car_list.append(carin)
        total = total + 1
    print 'You have returned' +str(amount) + 'car(s)'
    return rented_cars, car_list

def rental_system(self): 
    rentedcars = []
    rented = raw_input('Are you returning or renting a car? Type either return/rent ')
    if rented.lower() == 'return':       # Return system
        type = raw_input('Are you returning a petrol, electric, diesel or hybrid car? ')
        amount = raw_input('How many would you like to return? ')
        if type == 'petrol':
            self.rented(self.petrolcars, rentedcars, amount)
        elif type.lower() == 'diesel':
            self.rented(self.dieselcars, rentedcars, amount)
        elif type.lower() == 'hybrid':
            self.rented(self.hybridcars, rentedcars, amount)
        elif type.lower() == 'electric':
            self.rented(self.electriccars, rentedcars, amount)
        else:
            print 'Error, please check your spelling'
            return

    if rented.lower() == 'rent':
```

## Rental process

```
        answer = raw_input('What type of car would you like? Type: petrol/diesel/hybrid/electric ')
        amount = int(raw_input('How many of that type of car?'))
        if answer.lower() == 'petrol':
            self.rent(self.petrolcars, rentedcars, amount)
        elif answer.lower() == 'diesel':
            self.rent(self.dieselcars, rentedcars, amount)
        elif answer.lower() == 'hybrid':
            self.rent(self.hybridcars, rentedcars, amount)
        elif answer.lower() == 'electric':
            self.rent(self.electriccars, rentedcars, amount)
        else:
            print 'Error, please check your spelling'
            return
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If you get an error please add the complete Traceback. There are valuable information inside like what error occured under which cirumstances in which line. That way it's easier to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are passing an empty list through the `rental_system` method to the `rented` method.

You have defined `rentedcars = []` in `rental_system` method and without modifying it you are trying to pop from it in the `rented` method.

Why don't you add the `rented_cars` as an attribute in your class design?

Comment: Hi, tried it earlier - still the same answer. Tried moving it into rental_system to see if that would fix it by defining the list before it executed. Defining it as a class object tried under __init__, called it self.rentedcars = [], but when rest of equasion is modified to take new parameter name and original rentedcars removed it still returns empty list.

Comment: This is the class defenition for the lists; class Dealership(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.electriccars = [] 
        self.petrolcars = []   
        self.dieselcars = []    
        self.hybridcars = []   
        self.rentedcars = [] For the rent process this works but it wont for the returning process (popping from list of cars rented)

Comment: Read a little bit more about OOP in python. You don't need to pass attributes as parameters for methods. You should use `self` to address them.

Comment: Managed to resolve it, thanks for the help. Turns out defining it as self.rentalcars then returning the value at the end of the function did the trick